# Bug in rpm-maven-plugin with softlinkSorce, doesnt it?

Tags: java, maven, rpm-maven-plugin

```
...
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1-alpha-3</version>
...
<mapping>
    <directory>/etc/init.d/</directory>
    <softlinkSource>
        <location>/opt/activemq/bin/activemq</location>
    </softlinkSource>
</mapping>
...
```

Compiled with error:
    ...Cannot find setter, adder nor field in org... for 'softlinkSource'...

I find codehaus jira with same bug:
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRPM-82

It is fixed in my version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<mapping>
    <directory>/etc/init.d</directory>
    <sources>
        <softlinkSource>
        <location>
                /opt/activemq/bin/activemq
            </location>
        </softlinkSource>
    </sources>
</mapping>
```

this is right code